# Stop windows from force updating while java program is running

Tags: java, windows, updates

I have a custom java program that collects data unattended for a large period of time. From time to time windows updates thus stopping my program. Is there a way or library to pause windows updates while the program is running and then start them back up during exit?

Comment: Turn off automatic updates on Windows?..

Comment: Based https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10/946991, it appears the answer is no.